# bash scripting - removing trailing chars from the end of a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, bash-completion

I have a string like that:

rthbp-0.0.3-sources.jar

And i want to get a new string called in someway (like string2) with the original string with just the version , so - '0.0.3' now rthbp- at the start will remain constant but after version "-" (-sources.jar)  may change.

is that possible in bash, just to extract the version info ?

I am doing this  - echo ${f:6} but only gives me 0.0.3-sources.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using bash, you can extract an arbitrary substring by specifying both offset and length:

```
$ filename=rthbp-0.0.3-sources.jar
$ echo "${filename:6:5}"
#=> 0.0.3
```

But using exact character offsets like that is fragile.  You might want to use something like this:

```
$ IFS=- read pre version post <<<"$filename"
$ echo "$version"
#=> 0.0.3
```

Or, somewhat more clunkily:

```
$ ltrim=${filename%%-*}-
$ rest=${filename#$ltrim}
$ version=${rest%%-*}
```

Or as others mentioned you could call out to `cut` or `awk` to do the splitting for you..

Comment: The clunky code can be simplified a bit:`version_and_suffix=${filename#rthbp-}; version=${version_and_suffix%%-*}`

Comment: I was trying not to assume that we know the first part of the filename that exactly, but sure.

Answer (score 3):

No one has mentioned regular expression matching yet, so I will.

```
[[ $string1 =~ rthbp-(.*)-sources.jar ]]
version=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

(You may want a slightly more general regular expression; this just demonstrates how to match against a regular expression containing a capture group and how to extract the captured value.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read` built-in:

```
s='rthbp-0.0.3-sources.jar'
IFS=- read a ver _ <<< "$s" && echo "$ver"
0.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just using `cut` for this.  Define the delimiter as dashes and keep field two:

```
$ echo "rthbp-0.0.3-sources.jar" | cut -d'-' -f 2
0.0.3
```

If you want to use pure bash, you can use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion), but it isn't as clean.  Assuming the version always starts in the same place and is the same length, you can use:

```
$ str="rthbp-0.0.3-sources.jar"

$ echo "${str:6:5}"
0.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of regex match:

```
$ echo "rthbp-0.0.3-sources.jar"|grep -e '([[:digit:]]+\.)+[[:digit:]]+' -oP
0.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "rthbp-0.0.3-sources.jar" | awk -F- '$2=="0.0.3"{print $2}'
0.0.3


echo "rthbp-0.0.3-sources.jar" | awk -F- '{print $2}'
0.0.3
```